# 【cakephp2.9】複合ユニークキー設定時のsaveAllの挙動

Tags: mysql, cakephp

以下のようなテーブル構造があります。

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`item_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
`modified` datetime NOT NULL,
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `unique_keys` (`uid`,`item_code`)
)
```

uid:5, item_code:b-testのレコードがある状態で

```
$test = array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'item_code' => 'b-test',
        'uid' => '5'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'item_code' => 'w-test',
        'uid' => '5'
    )
);

$this->Product->saveAll($test);
```

このテーブルに対して上記のようなコードを実行すると

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5-b-test' for    key 'unique_keys'
```

と怒られてupdateになりません。
cakephpでは複合ユニークキーの保存と更新は出来ないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 2.x系は複合主キーに未対応です。

ModelクラスのprimaryKeyに依存する部分を書き換えることで、対応できなくもないですが副作用が大きいのでお勧めしません。

テーブルへサロゲートキーを追加してしまうのが一番の解法ですが、できない場合、複合主キーのテーブルへの保存についてはupdateAllなどを用いた保存メソッドを別途作成します。

なお、CakePHP 3.x系では複合主キーに対応しています。

Comment: サロゲーキーというのを知らなかったので、調べてprimarykeyにAutoIncrement属性のidを作ってみましたが、cakephpではprimaryKeyでしか判断してないのか、複合ユニークキーをsaveAllに含めても、全てinsertで入ってしまい理想の動作をしませんでした。
とりあえず現状はidにuid+item_codeで一意なデータを作成して入れることで対応しています。
それかSQL文を書いて対応したほうが良いのでしょうか。

Comment: 新規作成、更新の判定はprimaryKe‌​yしか見ていませんので、"idにuid+item_codeで一意なデータを作成" でよいと思います。